Can we light a lightbulb using Earth's electric field, if it was inside a medium with high charge density?
I know my question is similar to "Why can't we generate electricity from Earth's electric field?", but in that question the bulb is held in air, with terminals 1 meters apart. Here, light doesn't glow because of low charge density and conductivity in air, thus making the light bulb circuit open(off)
However, what makes my question unique is, in my question this experiment takes place in a medium with high density of movable charges/ions (e.g: molten sodium chloride, Con.HCl aqueous solution). The configuration is explained in the diagram below.

As you can see, in the above diagram, terminals are held apart in a sufficient distance from each other, so that there is a potential difference between the terminals. Bulb is isolated from ions so that it can't interact with any of the ions, so that there is a sufficient potential difference applied across the bulb. The whole setup is drowned completely in the above mentioned ionic medium.
So, would the bulb light up now, contrast to the situation when the setup was in atmosphere?
Also, (this is a side question) since there are movable charges, would those charges polarize in the medium, in a way that there is no net electric field in the medium? (would + and - ions separate into two layers)

Why should the charges move through the bulb, its easier ti move in the medium.

@trula yes, but what I want to know is, if there is a potential difference in the terminals in the above setup.

No, no potential difference, since you medium is a good conductor, so it is the same as just having a wire between the two points.

Can we power a turbine using Earth's gravitational field, if it was inside a fluid with high density?
The configuration is explained in the diagram below.

As you can see, in the above diagram, the inlet and outlet ports are held apart in a sufficient distance from each other, so that there is a pressure difference between the ports. The turbine is isolated from the pool so that it can't interact with the pool water, so that there is a sufficient pressure difference applied across the turbine. The whole setup is drowned completely in the water.
So, would the turbine spin? This would be a cheap solution to all of humantity's energy needs if it worked.

This is a question, not an answer.

@trula, This is not an answer, it's a comment. But, they don't let me put pictures in the little "Add a comment" box. My hope was, that the OP will see why my scheme won't work and, simultaneously see the isomorphism between my question and their own....

...Or maybe I'm playing "Jeopardy!" today, and it really is an answer, but it's an answer in the form of a question.

O k I understand that one could easily see the the comparison so its an answer. sorry
